# Error when passing argument to function to create sequence of dates in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function that takes the dates of a dataframe, and then creates a sequence based on the min and max of the date column from that dataframe:

```
seqgen <- function(date,data){
  sequ <- data.frame(seq(min(as.Date(date), max(as.Date(date)), "day" )))
  return(sequ)
}
```

However this returns error

> do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

If I do this outside of a function :

```
sequ <- data.frame(seq(min(as.Date(df$date)), max(as.Date(df$date)), "day"))
```

It works fine and creates the "sequ" data.frame.

The argument is already formatted as a date type.

df:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 
16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770, 16801, 16832, 16861), class = "Date"), 
    Aggregator.Spend..incl.VAT. = c(60902, 69361, 62905, 57568, 
    49662, 47222, 53818, 50798, 40480, 61323, 54975, 56608), 
    Affiliate.Spend..incl.VAT. = c(108508, 104398, 102589, 88613, 
    78514, 72745, 84362, 86809, 91729, 110143, 99682, 107421)), .Names = c("date", 
"Aggregator.Spend..incl.VAT.", "Affiliate.Spend..incl.VAT."), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of "df"?

Comment: Have provided dput in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modifying your function `seqgen`:

```
seqgen <- function(data){
  out <- with(data, seq(min(as.Date(date)), max(as.Date(date)), "day" ))
  sequ <- data.frame(Date = out)
  return(sequ)
}
```

`out <- with(data, seq(min(as.Date(date)), max(as.Date(date)), "day"))` uses the data.frame "data", i.e. the input of the function `seqgen` through the function `with` and read the column "date" to create the sequence. With `with`, you don't need to specify `data$date` in `seq`.

`sequ <- data.frame(Date = out)` write the result of `seq` into the data.frame "sequ", adding "Date" as column name.

`return(sequ)` returns the "sequ" data.frame outside the environment of the function

```
head(seqgen(df))
#         Date
# 1 2015-04-01
# 2 2015-04-02
# 3 2015-04-03
# 4 2015-04-04
# 5 2015-04-05
# 6 2015-04-06

tail(seqgen(df))
#           Date
# 331 2016-02-25
# 332 2016-02-26
# 333 2016-02-27
# 334 2016-02-28
# 335 2016-02-29
# 336 2016-03-01
```

Comment: Have tried modifying my code to this and am still getting the same error. Could you please explain to me why this would work over my original code?
Thanks.

Comment: So, this function doesn't work on your data.frame? At least, it works on the data.frame you provided.

Comment: Have tried your solution to no avail, can you provide any explanation as to why it would work as opposed to my original code? 
I am using the same data I put in the dput.

Comment: How are you passing the date argument to the function ? I am passing it in as df$date.

Comment: I have edited the answer. But this function works with your data.frame.

Comment: Thanks very much for the extra detail, but I'm still getting the error. I suspect it must be a conflict with some package I have turned on, so I will investigate that.

Comment: Yes, please. I am intersted in the reason it doesn't work for you.